# Martingale recursively defined on uniform random-variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, martingales, uniform-distribution

I am trying to solve the following exercise on martingale:
Let $X_n$ be the recursive process defined as follows:
$X_0 \sim \mathcal{U}([-1,+1]), X_n = \sim \mathcal{U}([-|X_{n-1}|,+|X_{n-1}|])$

is the process a martingale? 
Honestly I think it is a martingale, but how do I compute 
$E(X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n) = E[\mathcal{U}([-|X_{n}|,+|X_{n}|])|\mathcal{F}_n]$?

$X_{n+1}$ should take any value in the interval $[-|X_n|,+|X_n|]$ with probability $\sim \frac{1}{2|X_n|}$ , but I wouldn't Know how to compute the conditional expectation in this case, what is the proper way to formalize this?

Comment: Where? I just wrote what the exercise asked me to do, I didn't design it. Are you referring to my observation on the conditional expectation?

Comment: It is the absolute value of the value that the random variable $X_i$ take at time $n$. $X_{n+1}$ is defined recursively as a random variable which takes values uniformly in the interval $[-|X_n|,+|X_n|]$. Since we are considering martingales, when you consider $\mathcal{F}_n$ which represents the information you have about the process at time $n$ I think it is safe to define $X_{n+1}$ like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E}\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal F}$It is not a martingale. We prove it by contradiction, asssume it is a martingale. I assume $\F_n = \sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$. Then one has:
\begin{align*}\tag{1}
\E[X_{n+1} \mid \F_n ] =X_n 
\end{align*}
Notice that $\sigma(X_n)\subset \F_n$, so:
\begin{align}
\E[\E[X_{n+1}\mid \F_n ] \mid X_n]= \E[X_{n+1}\mid X_n]=0
\end{align}
Since the "smaller $\sigma$-algebra wins". Moreover: $$\E[X_n\mid X_n ] =X_n$$ Now condition on $\sigma(X_n)$ on both sides of $(1)$ to get: 
\begin{align}
0 = X_n \ \ \text{ a.s.}
\end{align}
This is clearly wrong, hence a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Neat proof! But then, how could $|X_n|$ be a super/sub-martingale instead?

Comment: @user1868607 no, if you change the equality in (1) to an inequality, then you get an inequality like $X_n\geq 0$ a.s. Or $X_n\leq 0$ a.s. Which is also a contradiction. So it cannot be super/sub martingale either.

Comment: I think it is wrong, I just tried to compute the conditional expectation $E[|X_{n+1}| \mid \mathcal{F}_n]$ and I think it is $\frac{|X_n|}{2} \leq |X_n|$. It probably is a super-martingale.

Comment: @user1868607 oh you meant $|X_n|$, I thought $X_n$